# How to convert a signed APK to an unsigned APK

Tags: android

i'm trying to convert a signed APK to an unsigned one, i can't find any solution on the web. is there any command line or any solution to do this on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea is to delete the `META-INF` folder bundled with your apk to make it unsigned. In windows, if you want to use GUI based systems, not all the file archiver tools can repack the apk in its original form after modification (In this case, deleting `META-INF` folder).

However, you can use command line to achieve what you want. You need to have [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) installed in your system and add its parent directory to the system path variable. Then, you can issue this command to unsign the apk:

```
7z d -tzip APPNAME.apk "META-INF*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands on Terminal

```
zip -d app.apk META-INF/BSFT.RSA
zip -d app.apk META-INF/BSFT.SF
```